# How to change a directory for your outputs in R

Tags: r

I have several files in a directory and I want to process these files and give there names to the output files:

code:

```
      dir1 <- list.files("/data/sm", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
      for (.files in seq_along(dir1)) {
         list1 <- readBin(dir1[.files], numeric(), size = 4, n = 1383*586)   
         ## I do calculations here##
         results[[length(results) + 1L]] <- list1  

      }
```

I have two problems in last three lines in this code:

- there are two dots (..) in the file names so `fileName` considers only the first `dot` and puts `img` after it for instance:
  original file: `sat_or.dl.img`

fileName "the output" would be `sat_or.img`

but I would like to have the same name? any help

- this will put the outputs in the same directory of dir1 but I want to puts the output files in a different directory? any help pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two functions to the rescue, `basename` and `file.path`:

```
outputDir  <- "/data/out"
outputFile <- file.path(outputDir, basename(dir1[i]))
```